# Каким образом расчитывается количество контекстов используемых в запросе в Firebird?

Tags: sql, firebird

Каков алгоритм при подсчете контекстов используемых в запросе в `Firebird`? 
учитываются только таблицы или `union` тоже?

```sql
select * from table1
union all
select * from table2
```

т.е. тут 3 контекста?

вопрос возник по причине возникновения ошибки вида

```
Dynamic SQL Error
Too many Contexts of Relation/Procedure/Views.
Maximum allowed is 255
```

Comment: Контекст - это любая ссылка на таблицу, представление или процедуру. Если я правильно понимаю, что там пишут в доках, показанный UNION скушает пять контекстов - два на исходные таблицы, два на подзапросы (вот тут я до конца не понял - едят они отдельные контексты или нет) и один на объединение. Опять же если я верно понимаю доки, лимит на контексты - хардкодный, и иного способа чем шинковка сложного запроса на куски, не придумали (по крайней мере до версии 2,5 включительно).

Comment: @Akina, Спасибо! да, пришлось заменить запрос с union all(кучей штук) на один селект с group by (в моем случае это было возможно), а так да печальная ситуация( с этим делом.